# How can I make a div 100% height fixed?

Tags: css, position, fixed

I want to a div with 100% height but fixed position like right side of this website:  http://www.dast2.com

I know these are required: height:100%; position:fixed;

but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: The right side of that website doesn't seem to have 100% height.

Answer (score 4):

Old but here it goes:

```
div#sidebar {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   bottom: 0px
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<body>

  <div id="sidebar">

  </div>

</body>
<style>

div#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color : #00FF00;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

</style>
```

[here is live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/madhawa11111/bcpn7311/)

Answer (score 2):

Using vh:

> Viewport Height (vh). This unit is based on the height of the
> viewport. A value of 1vh is equal to 1% of the viewport height.

```
height: 100vh;
```

Comment: when add height 100vh, then another div scrollbar on but scrollbar position in not propoerly work

Comment: may you give your code? or more infomation?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers dont calculate height so well.
`height: auto` means 'get the same height as your content'.
But `height: 100%` doesn't always plays well, because the content of an element defines its height. So the body height is defined by its content. So when you instruct your content to have `height: 100%`, you instruct it to have the same height as the body, but the body is the same height as the content, so you instruct it to be as tall as itself.

You must provide height to body and html ( root element ).

In this case, I made a demo, which I provided the html element a ridiculus `height: 10000px`.

For the sidebar ( the one with the red color ) the only property you need is the `min-height: 100%` property. The sidebar will take all of its vertical space as you can see in the demo below. Just added `position: fixed;` and `right:0` to make it fixed at the right.

Here is the **[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q7HI4c?p=preview)**

**Quick Note:** If you ever want to have  the same effect on live site, just inspect the page with the developer tools and grab the css/markup that fit your needs.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body{height:100%;}
```

follow this and give 100% to the div

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the container take max-width, check the all the container in youI think one of the container takes a property of max-width, check the container that holds the div.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have 'Display: block', for it to work.

THE HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Top bit</p>
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <p>Some content</p>
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <p>Bottom bit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fullHeight sidebar">
      <h1>Sticky sidebar</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

THE CSS:

```
.container   {width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; position: relative;}
.content     {width: 690; float: left; position: relative;}
.fullHeight  {height: 100%; display: block; overflow: hidden; position: fixed; width: 300px; background: red; right: 0; top: 0;}
```

I made the background red, so you could copy that code in, to see if it worked. I must admit, that I haven't tested it; but I'm fairly sure that that does the trick. Let me know if it doesn't work; then I'll test it and fix it.

And remember to have 'Position: relative;' on the element that the fixed element inside - so it 'knows' what it should be fixed relative to. If it's not inside a container or anything (like mine is above), then you can put 'Position: relative;' on the body-tag; like so:

```
body  {position: relative;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.bg-container{ 
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Please explain why and how this code solves OP's problem. Otherwise your answer will be deleted.

Comment: just test it will be work for you if you want a fixe and full wide div, don't need more explain kanaka.

Comment: A good explanation is an essential part of high-quality content, which is what makes StackOverflow stand out among other communities. So, If you can't explain your code, just leave a comment to the question instead of answering it.

Comment: excellent, you are right, but this code is simple I think don't need more explanation. if you think need it please review it.